# How to use parameters in constructor when facing CS0310 error

Tags: c#

I have created following abstraction for scheduling jobs:

```
public abstract class BaseJob
{
    public string? JobId { get; set; }
}

public interface IJobData
{ }

public interface IJob<in TJobData> where TJobData : IJobData
{
    Task ExecuteAsync(TJobData jobData);
}
```

I create jobs using a factory:

```
public class JobCreator<TJob, TJobData>
    where TJob : IJob<TJobData>, new()
    where TJobData : IJobData
{
    public async Task ExecuteAsync(TJobData jobData)
    {
        var job = new TJob();
        await job.ExecuteAsync(jobData);
    }
}
```

Example implementation:

```
public record ForgotPasswordJobData() : IJobData;

public class ForgotPasswordJob: BaseJob, IJob<ForgotPasswordJobData>
{
    private readonly IMailService _mailer;

    public ForgotPasswordJob(IMailer mailer)
    {
        _mailer = mailer;
    }

    public Task ExecuteAsync(ForgotPasswordJobData jobData)
    {
       // Do something
       // Send mail
    }
}
```

This is how a job is enqueued:

```
JobClient.Enqueue<JobCreator<ForgotPasswordJob, ForgotPasswordJobData>>(job => job.ExecuteAsync(jobData));
```

Because ForgetPasswordJob does not have a parameterless constructor I get a [CS0310](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0310?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0310)) error which is saying

> The type 'ForgotPasswordJob' must be a non-abstract type with a public
> parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'parameter'
> in the generic type or method 'JobCreator<IJob,IJobData>'

How can I use dependencies in implementations of IJob?

Comment: looks like you missing some tags here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to tell your `JobCreater` how to instantiate the `TJob`:

```
public class JobCreator<TJob, TJobData>
where TJob : IJob<TJobData>
where TJobData : IJobData
{
    public async Task ExecuteAsync(Func<TJob> createJob, TJobData jobData)
    {
        var job = createJob();
        await job.ExecuteAsync(jobData);
    }
}


var mailService = new MailService();
JobClient.Enqueue<JobCreator<ForgotPasswordJob, ForgotPasswordJobData>>(
    job => job.ExecuteAsync(() => new ForgotPasswordJob(mailService), jobData));
```

---

Although I'm not sure `JobCreator` is really necessary

You could change your `JobClient` to accept an already instantiated job, considering that does not rely on anything within Enqueue:

```
void Enqueue<TJob, TJobData>(TJob job, TJobData jobData)
where TJob : IJob<TJobData>
where TJobData : IJobData
{
    // ...
    Task jobTask = job.ExecuteAsync(jobData);
    // ...
}

var forgotPasswordJob = new ForgotPasswordJob(new MailService());
JobClient.Enqueue(forgotPasswordJob, jobData);
```

Comment: +1 thx! Is there a way to do this, without using () => new ForgotPasswordJob(mailService)? The underlaying job service cannot serialize this expression "Anonymous functions, delegates and lambda expressions aren't supported in job method parameters". Just using job => job.ExecuteAsync(jobData) works however.

Comment: @Upvote See my update; maybe you could remove your `JobCreator` entirely?

Comment: Love the idea. Works great!